# merge to linked lists, but an unusual None type error is occurring

Tags: python, class, object, linked-list

Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new sorted list. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

Example:

Input: `1->2->4, 1->3->4`
Output: `1->1->2->3->4->4`

- I know this is not the optimal solution but still I'm not able to understand my mistake.*

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(ListNode):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        lst =[]
        while(l1!=None):
            #print("I")
            lst.append(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next
        while (l2!=None):
            #print("I")
            lst.append(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next
        lst.sort()
        #print(lst)
        l = ListNode(0)
        #temp : ListNode()
        temp = l
       # temp.val = l.val
        for i in lst:
            temp.val = i
            temp = temp.next
        return l
```

**error is**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
    temp.val = i
```

Comment: What do you mean by `mistake` what issue are you facing?

Comment: i added the error now please see it

Comment: You are not making a new ListNode object for temp. Use temp = ListNode(i) to make a new node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with below line

```
temp = temp.next
```

You initialize `temp` as `l` but it doesn't have any next element, it's just a single element. In other words `temp.next` is `None` so whenever you go to 2nd iteration of the for loop you will see `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'`

**Solution:**

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
lst = [1,2,3,4]

l = ListNode(lst[0])
temp = l
for i in lst[1:]:
    temp.next = ListNode(i)
    temp = temp.next
```

Comment: oh! now i get it, so it should be ```temp.next = ListNode(i)``` instead of ```temp.val=i```

Comment: @AbritPalSingh You should mark an answer as accepted green tick on left side if it helped you.

Comment: Ok cool.. I think I don't have that many reputation points and it's not displayed to the public